# Running guard as a daemon proces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, guard

I am using guard to watch a directory, as soon as files are uploaded into the directory Guard a rake process gets triggered.

Is there any way to run Guard as a daemon process, Not been able to find out anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Guard does not have a built in option to run as daemon, but you could use [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) and [ampersand](http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand) to run it in the background:

```
nohup guard &
```

Running in the background should not print anything to the console, so I'd redirect the streams:

```
nohup guard >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

In that case I'd recommend to deactivate the interactor and use file logging in your `Guardfile`:

```
interactor :off
logger device: 'guard.log'
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, i.e. run guard as a daemon, you can supply the `daemon` option to `guard` as:

```
guard 'rails', daemon: true do
  watch(...)
  ...
end
```

Reference other [guard options](https://github.com/ranmocy/guard-rails#lots-of-fun-options-growing).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input, but i assume the reference you have provide is for guard-rails.
I wanted guard itself to run as a daemon process.
The guard gem.

Comment: BTW, you posted your question with a "ruby on rails" tag, and actually most people use guard-rails (like me), so this answer was actually more relevant for me

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to the documentation [to start guard programmatically on Rails](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Use-Guard-programmatically-cookbook#starting-guard-within-your-application) ;)

In short, create an initializer for Guard containing:

```
require 'guard'
require 'guard/commander' # needed because of https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/793

# Start Guard only with rails.
if File.basename($0, '.*') == 'rails'
  fork do
    if __FILE__ == '(irb)'
    end

    Guard.guards 'sass'
    Guard.start :no_interactions => true
  end
end
```